# Multi-Column Page Layout using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

[image: two column page layout react-pdf]

The above picture is an example of a two-column page layout system in MS Word. On the web, a similar layout can be achieved using the following code:

```html
<style>
.two-col {
  column-count: 2;
}
</style>
<div class="two-col">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

How can it be done with `react-pdf`?

I tried with flexbox styling but it only works for a single page; continuous text wrapping or page breaking is impossible.

Comment: I found my answer in this link https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/430 Hope it helps you!